Integrating Vue.js 3 and Laravel in a Single Project with a JavaScript Template
I am working on a project with Vue.js 3 for the front-end and Laravel for the back-end, but both in the same project. To speed up the project's development, I purchased a template made in vanilla JavaScript. I placed the files in the public folder and imported them into my welcome.blade.php as follows :
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tracking</title>

    <!-- Favicon  -->
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('assets/img/favicon.png')}}" />
    <!-- Icon Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/fonts/iconfonts/font-awesome/stylesheet.css')}}" />
    <!-- Site font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/fonts/webfonts/inter/stylesheet.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/fonts/webfonts/plus-jakarta-sans/stylesheet.css')}}" />

    <!-- Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/vendors/swiper-bundle.min.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/vendors/jos.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/vendors/menu.css')}}" />

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/custom.css')}}" />

    <!-- Development css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    <!--Vendor js-->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/vendors/counterup.js')}}" type="module"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/vendors/swiper-bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/vendors/fslightbox.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/vendors/jos.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/vendors/menu.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Main js -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/main.js')}}"></script>
</body>

</html>

I'm using Vue Router, and I've noticed that when I switch from one route to another, the JavaScript files don't work unless I refresh the page first
I tried using Vue.js hooks, but it doesn't work

"when I switch from one route to another" - what exactly do you do? "JavaScript files don't work" - in which way, are there any errors?
